# how to submit "multipart/form-data" from VueJs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, multipartform-data, multer, axios

I am using VueJs / axios in frontend and multer in nodejs for a simple file upload to work.

So far all tries has been unsuccessful. 
While this can be achieved in 100 ways in angular 1/2 using ng-upload and other similar plugins. But VueJs seems to be lacking this basic functionality.
Based on my research axios doesnt support "multipart/form-data". Ref https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/789 .

multer and other nodejs libraries seems to work with "multipart/form-data" seamlessly from angular 1/2. However same functionality is not working from VueJs.

Is there any other alternative other than axios which support "multipart/form-data" aka -- WebKitFormBoundary  ??

Many Thanks

Comment: Well Axios isn't the only library out there...what about Vue Resource https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/267 ? Yes I know they said..but for me it still works pretty fine

Comment: The referred link says that **node.js** doesn't support `FormData` objects. Nor should it really, `FormData` is a browser construct. Axios supports submitting FormData *from a browser* just fine. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/aWmomM?editors=1010

Comment: @BertEvans - Many thanks for the input. Yes it works both with axios and new XMLHttpRequest() using formData(). Is FormData an good solution   ?. http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData

Comment: @Sumanta Depends on your use case, but generally it's fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found two ways of achieving this in VueJs. There might be more.

**Option 1. Using Axios. Based on answer by Bert Evans above**

```js
const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", _file);
  formData.append("id", 7878);
  axios.post("/api/uploadFile", formData)
    .then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
    }, function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

**Option 2. Using Native XMLHttpRequest()**`

```js
 var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", _file);
  formData.append("id", 7878);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "/api/uploadFile");
  request.send(formData);
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
      if (request.status === 200 && request.statusText === 'OK') {
        console.log('successful');
      } else {
        console.log('failed');
      }
    }
  }
```

An interesting point of FormData() browser support here [caniuseFormData](http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData)

Also for those trying like me to make it work with content-type = "multipart/form-data" with axios. It won't work.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for that and it is pretty easy.

Let me show you an example:

```
// html    
<button ref="uploadBtn" @onChange="upload">Upload Files</button>

// js
methods: {
    upload () {
        let files = this.$refs.uploadBtn.files
        let formData = new FormData()

        // if you want to upload multiple files at once loop 
        // through the array of files
        formData.append('attachment', files[0])
        axios.post(url, formData).then(response => ...)
    }
}
```

This should do the trick and you don't really need a 3rd party plugin for that.

Comment: Indeed, this is more convenient, IMHO

Answer (score 2):

i have also faced the an issue where i have to send some other info along with image. i would like to share what i did.
**I am trying to upload image, kind, name and eventID.**

```
let logo1 = new FormData
logo1.append('image', this.logo1)
logo1.append('kind', 'logo1')
logo1.append('name', this.$refs.logo1.files[0].name )
logo1.append('eventID',eventID)


axios.post(`/upload`, logo1,
        
  {
    headers:{
      'Authorization' : `${token}`,
      'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${logo1._boundary}` 
 },    

 }).then((res) => {

     console.log(res)


}).catch((error) => {

    console.log(error)

})
```

Note: The postdata param format should be ***(url , FormData)*** and not (url, {data: FormData})

Comment: Adding "boundary" to headers solved my problem (after 3-4 hours). Thank you so much!