# $request->file keeps returning tmp path

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to upload a file using laravel and vue. When i console.log() the file, I get the picture below but in the controller, I'm receiving a tmp path only.

[image: console log result]

**Vue**

```
onFileChange(e) {
   ths.file = e.target.files[0];
   console.log(this.file)
},
submit(){
   let form= new FormData()
   form.append('file', this.file)
   axios.post('/api/archieve',form).then(res=>{
            //
   })
},
```

**Controller**

```
return $request->file //returns "C:\xampp\tmp\php5E67.tmp"
```

**UPDATE**
I've checked using dd($request->file('file')); and it returns the below image but the realPath is wrong. The image is stored in a different folder on my pc.

[image]

Comment: check inside `$request->file()`

Comment: if you have `content-type = "multipart/form-data"` in your form remove it as this answer is saying it caused him problems https://stackoverflow.com/a/43584379/1545904

Comment: @V-K returns empty file.

Comment: @zizoujab no i didnt cause FormData() already include by default

Comment: @V-K sorry, it returns the same thing C:\xampp\tmp\php8F5A.tmp

Answer (score 2):

Please try add header.

```
  onFileChange(e) {
    this.file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(this.file)
  },
  submit() {
    let form= new FormData()
    form.append('file', this.file)
    axios.post('/api/archieve', form,  {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    }).then(res=>{
      //
    })
  },
```

and in you controller, check

```
$request->file('file');
```

To store file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
....

$file = $request->file('file');

$path = 'my-uploads'; // path or folder where to save it
$storePath = Storage::put($path, $file);
$fileName = basename($storePath);  // generated file name

$filePath = $path . '/' . $fileName; // path of file in your storage
```

Comment: still the same. getting tmp path only

Comment: yes, it will return path. try `dd($request->file('file'));` and check in console networks

Comment: that's it! now you can store the file `$storePath = Storage::put($pathInStorage, $file);`

Comment: but why is the realPath is wrong, the image is inside another folder